# Hibernate exception: No Hibernate Session bound to Thread

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am trying to use Hibernate when I attempt to open a Session I get the following Exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested 
exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread,        
and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)

root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:622)
    com.dataart.masternoy.dao.imp.UserDAOImpl.existUserByLoginEmail(UserDAOImpl.java:35)
    com.dataart.masternoy.service.imp.UserServiceImpl.existUserByLoginMail(UserServiceImpl.java:47)
    com.dataart.masternoy.controller.FirstPageController.isValid(FirstPageController.java:46)
    com.dataart.masternoy.controller.FirstPageController.ConfirmRegister(FirstPageController.java:79)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
```

here is my config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd"        
    default-lazy-init="true">
    <import resource="applicationContext-services.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-security.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-email.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-social.xml" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.name." />
    <bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basename" value="messages" />
      <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
      <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
      </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Dispatcher Servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.name" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <!-- 
     <mvc:view-controller path="/error/" view-name="errors/error" /> 
     <mvc:view-controller path="/403/" view-name="errors/403" /> 
     <mvc:view-controller path="/404/" view-name="errors/404" /> 
     <mvc:view-controller path="/405/" view-name="errors/405" /> 
    -->
</beans>
```

Services

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" /> -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="configProperties" class="com.dataart.masternoy.utils.PropertiesUtil">
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
      <property name="locations">
        <list>
          <value>classpath:/config.properties</value>
          <value>classpath:/jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSourceNew"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" /> -->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />

    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" id="jdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          lazy-init="true">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceNew" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.name" />
      <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernateConfig.xml</value>
      </property>
      <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
      </property>
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
          <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
          <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And serviceImpl

```
@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("UserDAO")
UserDAO userDAO;

@Transactional
public void addNewUser(User user) {
    userDAO.insertNewUser(user);
}
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public User getUserByLogin(String login) {
    return userDAO.selectUserByLogin(login);
}
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<User> getUserList() {
    return userDAO.getUserList();
}
@Transactional
public void removeUserByLogin(String login) {
    userDAO.deleteUserByLogin(login);
}
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Boolean existUserByLoginMail(String login, String email) {
    return userDAO.existUserByLoginEmail(login, email);
}
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public User getUserByID(Long ID) {
    return (User) userDAO.selectUserByID(ID);
}
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public User getUserByLoginPass(String login, String pass) {
    return userDAO.getUserByLoginPass(login, pass);
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate @Transactional Sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895451/hibernate-transactional-sessions). You got an answer for the other identical question you asked, and you even accepted the answer. Why are you re-asking it once again?

Comment: No it no the same problem. Now it deploys but can not open Session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my guess. In a Spring MVC application the context used by the dispatcher servlet is a child of the global context. So if you configure the same beans in this child context as the ones configured in the global context, the child context beans will override the global ones.

This is probably what you did, which means that you get a reference to a UserService instantiated by the child context, where there is no transaction manager, instead of getting a reference to the UserService instantiated by the global context, where the transaction manager is defined.

Make sure to only scan MVC-related beans in your MVC context, by changing

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.name" />
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.name.web" />
```

or to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.name">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

for example.

Comment: What package is com.company.name.web?

Comment: A fictional package where you have all your MVC-related stuff, and none of your services and DAOs. Re-reading your stack trace, it could be com.company.name.controller.

Comment: If i change context:component scan in appContext to anything else such as com.company.name.controller. it even not compile.

Comment: Wow!!! It Works!!!

I delete mvc:annotation driven in dispatcher-Servlet. And it create session and save Object in DB. OMFG.